# convert array values in comma separated in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

i have an array variable which has some integer value.
I need to feed that variable in some other function as comma separated value, can someone point me how it can be done.
Please note am using powershell to perform the required things.

thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: Use `-Join` See an example: `$Array = @(1,2,3,4,5) ; $Array -join ','`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-join` operator to join array elements. This creates a single string that is comma-delimited.

```
$array -join ','
```

---

Since you are trying to create a JSON array, it is easier to work with PowerShell custom objects first and then convert them to JSON.

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{'Name'='export-docs';'fileIds'=$array}
$botBody = $obj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
$botBody # JSON string
```

Comment: Thanks this solves my first issue. However, I need further clarification.I need to pass those array values in Request body. something like below botBody = '{
  "name": "export-docs",
  "fileIds": [  array values with comma separated (10, 21, 100, 30 ],
  "includePackages": true
}'. The issue am facing that am not able to publish variable value in the body of request. I was playing with single and double quotes but still it didn't work out. Any suggestion. how to overrcome it.

Comment: You are overcomplicating it from a PowerShell perspective. It is better to just work with a custom object and convert it to JSON.